# On limits of functions and derivative

Tags: limits

If the limit of $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ each tends to zero as $x$ tends to $a$, is $f'(a)=0?$ Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't seem necessarily true because $f'$ is not necessarily continuous, so it may be the case that $\lim_{x\to a}f'(x)\neq f'(a)$.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. But f is continuous I forgot to add. Please I need a proof to this or a counter example. Thanks.

Comment: I think you need $f'$ to be also continuous at $x=a$. For instance, $f(x)=x|x-a|-ax$ is continuous and the $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x) = 0$. Similarly, $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^{+}}f'(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{x(x-a)}{|x-a|}+|x-a|-a = 0$. Yet, the $f'(a)$ is not defined. In this example you have the limit from one side is not the same as the limit from the other side. I believe if you require both limit to exist and be the same, then by definition the limit at $x=a$ of $f'$ also exists and is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $f$ is differentiable at each point the answer is YES. $\frac {f(a+h)-f(a)} h =f'(x_h)$ for some $x_h$ between $a$ and $a+h$ (by Mean Value Theorem) . Since $ f'(x_h) \to 0$ we get $f'(a)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

You have no constraint on domain, so $f$ need not be defined at $a$.  So let $f(x) = 0$ with domain $\Bbb{R} \smallsetminus \{a\}$.  Then $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f'(x) = 0$ but neither $f$ nor $f'$ is defined at $a$.